# MySql Ngram, prioritize a similar length instead of the number of occurrences

Tags: mysql, n-gram

Using MySql Ngram, I try to find in my table the film with the name most similar to my search.

I get the following result searching for "dragons 3":

```
SELECT name ,MATCH(slug) AGAINST ('dragons 3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM movie_be where MATCH(slug) AGAINST ('dragons 3' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

```
NAME                                                                  SCORE
Dragons : Première course de dragons - Prêt, feu,...                  17.32415771484375
Dragons 3 : Le monde caché                                            8.662078857421875
```

Like with PGSQL trgm, I want to prioritize the film whose name has the closest length and also contains "3" characters but it seems to prioritize the number of occurences of "dragons".

How could i do that ?

Thanks for your help